# page.evaluate does not seem to happen

Tags: javascript, async-await, puppeteer

As per the subject, my page.evaluate doesn't seem to run.

```
crawler.crawlUrl = async function(url) {
    if (!url) {
        return;
    }
    const page = await crawler.browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    console.log('got to here');
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const links2 = document.querySelectorAll('*');
        console.log('what');
        console.log(links2);
        return Promise.resolve(true);

    }).catch(function(er){
        console.log(er);
    });
}

crawler.crawlUrl('https://www.sundhed.dk');
```

When running this I end up with the 'Got to here' statement logging to the terminal but nothing else happens. It just sits around forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try waiting for something to come back! My rule of thumb is every time I ask for a new resource (click a button, goto a url) I **always** perform a `waitForXXX`

```
await page.goto(url);
await page.waitForSelector("h1");
```

You may need to replace the h1 with something that does exist on the page.

[View list of puppeteer selectors](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options)

I have created a script that works fine for me:-

Try waiting for something to come back! My rule of thumb is every time I ask for a new resource (click a button, goto a url) I **always** perform a `waitForXXX`

```
await page.goto(url);
await page.waitForSelector("h1");
```

You may need to replace the h1 with something that does exist on the page.

[View list of puppeteer selectors](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectorselector-options)

I have created a script that works fine for me:-

```
'use strict'; 

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer'); 

async function run() {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch( {
        headless: false //true
    }); 

    const page = await browser.newPage(); 
    await page.setViewport({ width:1024, height:800});
    await page.goto('https://www.sundhed.dk');
    await page.waitForSelector('h1');

    const innerText = await page.evaluate(() => {
        return document.querySelector("H1").innerText;
    });

    console.log(innerText);

    await browser.close(); 
}; 

run();
```

Comment: nope, tried both await page.waitForSelector("a"); and await page.waitForSelector("*"); different times, the wait for selector was before the console.log got to here, still get to that console.log but nothing inside the page.evaluate runs.

Comment: hmm, I figured that out. I needed to add the 
    page.on('console', msg => { console.log(msg); }); to get console output.

Comment: ah yes the question title misled me. to get console log from the dom you need to create the event `page.on(...)`. However said I would recommend to return what you want from evaluate and process it in the main script. HTH